# issues Creating a validation list in VBA for the cells in my variable size table, String is not working

Tags: excel, vba, string, validation, syntax-error

I Have a table that moves in numbers of rows, once its generated, i want that my columns C and D become validations list of time. so I have a VBA code, but I either get an error message when it gets to formula1 or instead of using the list inside my string, the menu i get is the name of my string variable i created.

the list i want to use is on a different page called "Support Gant"
The table I want to modify is on the "Rouge" sheet

I suppose i have a synthax error, but I can't find it

This is my part of my code

```vb
Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Dim wsData As Worksheet
Dim wsSupportGant As Worksheet
Dim rngData As Range
Dim rngSupportGant As Range
Dim strFormula As String

    ' Set the worksheet objects
    Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Rouge")
    Set wsSupportGant = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Support Gant")
    
    ' Set the data range and support gant range objects
    Set rngData = wsData.Range("C2:D" & wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
    Set rngSupportGant = wsSupportGant.Range("A2:A23")
    
    ' Set the validation formula string "=" &
    strFormula = "=" & wsSupportGant.Name & "!" & rngSupportGant.Address
    
     Dim cell2 As Range
    For Each cell2 In Range("C5:D" & LastRow)
        With cell2.Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:=strFormula  'this is where i get the error
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
        End With
    Next cell2
```

Comment: `For Each cell2 In Range("C5:D" & LastRow)` is this on a specific worksheet?  wsData or wsSupportGant ?

Answer (score 0):

Worksheet names with spaces need single quotes, so:

```
strFormula = "='" & wsSupportGant.Name & "'!" & rngSupportGant.Address
```

Comment: with this syntax I get the error 438 : Object doesn't support this property or method, I'll try to rename the sheet for something without space

Comment: Which line is the error on?

Comment: when it gets to the  strFormula =/.../  to put things in

Comment: Now i get the error before the validation starts is what I mean. It doesn't like what i try to put in the string